# How can I get Dash lenses to see files in network shares?

Tags: networking, unity-dash, lenses, search, cifs

I'd love to get more use out of the Dash files/music/video/photos lenses, but **all** of my documents and media are on (CIFS) network shares. These shares are always mounted and the files always available, but I don't see the results I should when I run file-related searches on the Dash. Sample searches do return the relevant files if I copy them into my desktop or elsewhere on the local system, so I know it's not an issue with Dash not being able to parse the files.

Is this something that can be enabled via a setting tweak/change? Some way to let Unity/Dash know it's okay to search/index network shares? Should it already be doing this out of the box and it's just not working on my particular setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my own problem (+1 to my "Linux user" cred!):

Unity does attempt to find files you search for via the Dash, but the default configuration for the file indexing tool it uses behind the scenes ("locate") blacklists a bunch of directories and filesystem types. What you want to do is edit your **/etc/updatedb.conf** file and remove some of these exclusions.

For my particular use case, I removed "/media" from the *PRUNEPATHS* directive and "nfs"/"cifs" from the *PRUNEFS* directive. If you then **sudo updatedb** to re-index the system, you should find Dash file searches behave as you'd expect.